# How to parse a String of xml in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to parse an XML String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522874/best-way-to-parse-an-xml-string-in-java)

I have a String value which is actually an xml data. I have to parse the String of xml data and get individual value from it. How can we do this?

Comment: Search for XML parser in java. There are lots of different XML parser in java available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522874/best-way-to-parse-an-xml-string-in-java

Comment: Yes, possible duplicate. @Marshal, have a look at SAX and DOM Parsers to get started. Here in Java 1.4.2 : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different XML APIs in Java - some built into the framework, some not.

One of the simpler ones to use is [JDOM](http://jdom.org):

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(new StringReader(text));

// Now examine the document, perhaps by XPath or by navigating
// programmatically, like this:

String fooContents = doc.getRootElement()
                        .getChild("foo")
                        .getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

for example [xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/). It is very simple