# How to convert string to arary[][] in Java

Tags: java

I have below string which I get from an xml file.

```
<product>
<aa>1367</aa>
<ac>133787</ac>
<db>13345</db>
<ce>133</ce>
<er>135</er>
<et>130</et>
<ef>14</ef>
</product>
```

How do I convert it to an two dimension array like

```
product[][]={{"aa", "1367"},{"ac","133787"}, {"db","13345"}....}
```

I only want to use string function and loop.

Comment: its an xml string, make your life easier by using one of the available xml parser.

Comment: You can use CofeeDom Java XML Parser https://code.google.com/p/coffeedom/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse an XML String in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522874/best-way-to-parse-an-xml-string-in-java)

Comment: @nes1983: Let's try not to be mean to the new people, okay? *Yes*, the question lacks the appearance of effort. By all means call them on it, but can we leave the sarky out? :-)

Comment: @Makky CofeeDom seem to be a fork of the outdated jdom1 implementation. I would not recommend to use this while jdom2 is available!

Comment: cannot use the any code out of java core

Comment: @user2642375: Whyever not?!

Comment: use it in webmethods java service, admin will not install the extra for me

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to use an available XML parser.
In this thread: [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) you'll probably find which one is the best to use